# Type of Python function pointer

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, annotations, function-pointers

For Python 3, it turned out as a good practise for me, to hint data types for function parameters and return types. For example:

```
def icecream_factory(taste: str='Banana') -> Ice:
    ice = Ice(taste)
    ice.add_cream()
    return ice
```

This works perfectly for all simple data types and classes. But now I need to use this with a "function pointer":

```
class NotificationRegister:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__function_list = list()
        """:type: list[?????]"""

    def register(self, function_pointer: ?????) -> None:
        self.__function_list.append(function_pointer)

def callback():
    pass

notification_register = NotificationRegister()
notification_register.register(callback)
```

What must be put at the `?????` to make clear that a function pointer is required here? I tried `function`, because `type(callback)` is `<class 'function'>`, but the keyword `function` is not defined.

Comment: Why not just a string - `function_pointer: "function"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) to represent a function:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType
<class 'function'>
>>>
>>> def func():
...     pass
...
>>> type(func)
<class 'function'>
>>> isinstance(func, types.FunctionType)
True
>>>
```

You could also use a string literal such as `'function'`, but it looks like you want an actual type object.

Comment: This seems to be a very good, straight forward and easy to remember approach. I'll go the way with the types package.

Answer (score 9):

use `Typing.Callable`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

> Frameworks expecting callback functions of specific signatures might be type hinted using `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```py
> from typing import Callable
>
> def feeder(get_next_item: Callable[[], str]) -> None:
>     # Body
>
> def async_query(on_success: Callable[[int], None],
>                 on_error: Callable[[int, Exception], None]) -> None:
>     # Body
> ```
>
> It is possible to declare the return type of a callable without specifying the call signature by substituting a literal
> ellipsis for the list of arguments in the type hint: `Callable[..., ReturnType]`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It allows to document arguments and return, and it uses a standard providing by "typing".. so its made for this purpose.

Comment: Current docs link: [Annotating callable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callable-objects)

Answer (score 4):

### *1. Basic idea*

Show basic idea of function callback's type in python.
Frameworks expecting callback functions of specific signatures might be type hinted at using

```
Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]
```

In your case, you want to use the function callback() without argument and return.
So it will be **Callable[[], None]**

### *2. The code can work*

I improve your code to support the above idea.
Then, you can run this code and the result will be correct.

```
from typing import Callable
class NotificationRegister:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__function_list:List[Callable[[],None]] = list()

    def register(self, function_pointer: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
        self.__function_list.append(function_pointer)

def callback():
    pass

notification_register = NotificationRegister()
notification_register.register(callback)
```

### *3. More detail to learn*

More information here gives you more idea about how to use a different type of function callback in python.

The document of Callable is in the following, but using **from typing import Callable** is better than using **from collections.abc import Callable** in my python 3.7 environments.

So I suggest you can use typing instead of collections.abc if your environment is python3.7.
[image]

If you want to learn more, then you can read this full document
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 1):

One approach may be to use [`collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable):

```
>>> import collections.abc
>>> def f(): pass
>>> isinstance(f, collections.abc.Callable)
True
```

This is intended for all objects that implement `__call__`. This is quite broad as it'll also be `True` for methods of instances or other objects that happen to implement `__call__`. But this may be what you intend - it depends on whether you only wish to accept functions or also other callable objects.